# Pandas : Optimising multiple sequential for loops

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have a dataframe `df` like below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

data = {'Name': ['XYZ', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'PQR', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'ABC'], 'Init_Time': ['2022-02-16 14:00:31', '2022-02-16 14:03:15', '2022-02-16 14:05:26',
                                                                                           '2022-02-16 14:06:23', '2022-02-16 14:10:00', '2022-02-16 14:12:36', 
                                                                                           '2022-02-16 14:14:11', '2022-02-17 07:07:25', '2022-02-17 15:08:35', 
                                                                                           '2022-02-17 15:09:46'], 'Category_flag': [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0], '10min_window_group': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Init_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Init_Time'])
print(df)

  Name           Init_Time  Category_flag  10min_window_group
0  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:00:31              1                   1
1  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:03:15              1                   1
2  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:05:26              0                   1
3  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:06:23              0                   1
4  PQR 2022-02-16 14:10:00              1                   1
5  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:12:36              0                   2
6  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:14:11              1                   2
7  ABC 2022-02-17 07:07:25              1                   3
8  XYZ 2022-02-17 15:08:35              0                   4
9  ABC 2022-02-17 15:09:46              0                   4
```

I'm assigning duplicate flags (`Duplicate_Flags`) (1/0) for each of the names of column `Name` that falls under a 10-minute window interval belonging to each of the category flags by filtering :

1. The column 'Name`, first (XYZ, PQR, ...)
2. The column `Category_Flag`, second (1/0).
3. The column `10min_window_group`, third (1/2/3/4).

For instance, in order to find duplicates of `XYZ` in the first 10-minute interval of the category `1`, we first filter Name i.e `XYZ` among unique names of `Name`, then we filter for which `category_flag` we want to find duplicates which in this case is 1, before finally filtering the 10-minute window grouping value i.e 1. In order to achieve this goal, I have utilized 3 `for` loops which work well in most cases, however, the issue is that it consumes a lot of computational time when the number of data points is very large (say like 2 million data points) since the code needs to iterate through all the 3 `for` loops.

```
for name in df['Name'].unique().tolist(): #Iterate over unique names of column `Name`.
  df1 = df[df['Name'] == name]
  for category in df1['Category_flag'].unique().tolist(): #Iterate over unique category flag values.
    df2 = df1[df1['Category_flag'] == category]
    for group in df['10min_window_group'].unique().tolist(): #Iterate over unique window interval values.
      df3 = df2[df2['10min_window_group'] == group]

      if(len(df3) > 0): #Check if the len of df3 is greater than 0.
        df3['Duplicates_flag'] = np.where(df3['Name'].duplicated(), 0, 1) #Finds the duplicates.
        df3_indices = df3['Duplicates_flag'].index #fetch index of duplicates
        df3_values = df3['Duplicates_flag'].values #fetch the values of duplicates.

        df.loc[df3_indices, 'Duplicates_flag'] = df3_values #Assign the duplicate values to the main `df` using the indices.

      elif(len(df3) == 1):
        df3['Duplicates_flag'] = np.where(df3['Name'].duplicated(), 0, 1)
        df3_indices = df3['Duplicates_flag'].index
        df3_values = df3['Duplicates_flag'].values

        df.loc[df3_indices, 'Duplicates_flag'] = df3_values


print(df)

  Name           Init_Time  Category_flag  10min_window_group  Duplicates_flag
0  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:00:31              1                   1              1.0
1  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:03:15              1                   1              0.0
2  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:05:26              0                   1              1.0
3  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:06:23              0                   1              0.0
4  PQR 2022-02-16 14:10:00              1                   1              1.0
5  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:12:36              0                   2              1.0
6  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:14:11              1                   2              1.0
7  ABC 2022-02-17 07:07:25              1                   3              1.0
8  XYZ 2022-02-17 15:08:35              0                   4              1.0
9  ABC 2022-02-17 15:09:46              0                   4              1.0
```

So, is there a way where in I can optimize the code by reducing the number of 3 `for` loops/replacing the 3 `for` loops? The primary aim is to reduce the computation time and make the code more computationally time efficient so that it results in the same output as above.

Comment: The `data` you've given doesn't produce the dataframe at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @NuriTaş : updated the data to reflect the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use `transform` after `groupby`:

```
df['Duplicates_flag'] = ( df.groupby(['Name', 'Category_flag', '10min_window_group'])
           ['10min_window_group'].transform(lambda x: ~x.duplicated()*1) )
```

Output:

```
    Name    Init_Time Category_flag 10min_window_group Duplicates_flag
0   XYZ 2022-02-16 14:00:31 1   1   1
1   XYZ 2022-02-16 14:03:15 1   1   0
2   XYZ 2022-02-16 14:05:26 0   1   1
3   XYZ 2022-02-16 14:06:23 0   1   0
4   PQR 2022-02-16 14:10:00 1   1   1
5   XYZ 2022-02-16 14:12:36 0   2   1
6   XYZ 2022-02-16 14:14:11 1   2   1
7   ABC 2022-02-17 07:07:25 1   3   1
8   XYZ 2022-02-17 15:08:35 0   4   1
9   ABC 2022-02-17 15:09:46 0   4   1
```

Comment: Tas : thanks for the answer, I have a quick question : How to get the count of duplicate values based on `Duplicates_Flag` ? For instance, duplicate count value will be 2 at row 0 and row 3, 1 at row 4..

Comment: similar function but put `count`: `.transform('count')`